# pandas HDFStore select rows with non-null values in the data column

Tags: pandas, hdf5

In pandas Dataframe/Series there's a `.isnull()` method. Is there something similar in the syntax of `where=` filter of the select method of HDFStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION:**

The `/meta` section of a data column inside hdf5 can be used as a *hack* solution:

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')

print(store.groups)

non_null = list(store.select("/df/meta/my_data_column/meta")) 

df = store.select('df', where='my_data_column == non_null')
```